# Samba/Linux: How to register only certain IP-Adresses in Windows AD DNS?

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory, debian, samba

I have set up Samba 4.12.14-Deb on Jessie as a member server for my AD and (so far) everything works fine. This machine does have a few `Tun*` Interfaces for openVPN tunnels (which are also working fine). Samba has to listen on those and it does perfectly (thanks to the `interfaces` setting in smb.conf).

Now, after every reboot, samba (I assume) registers alle the IP adresses listed in `smb.conf` as dynmic A records in my AD DNS. As good as this concept is, this causes a lot of trouble here, obviously. In Windows I can just uncheck the 'register this connection in DNS' option.

**How do I prevent Samba (or whoever does this) from registering "all the adresses"?**

Or, if that's not possible, how do I prevent it from registering itself in my DNS at all? In my case, a static (non-changing) entry would be more helpful than all the `tun`adresses.

Answer (score 2):

I actually wanted to get the answer from here, but couldn't ask if you have solved it, so here is the solution which works with at least samba 4.11

```
interfaces = 10.1.1.1
```

The interfaces parameter actually also understands IPs and Subnets, so you can put there all the ips that are necessary to be registered. You can then also use

```
bind interfaces only = yes
```

to limit samba to listen to those IPs or to listen on 0.0.0.0

In your case, where there are tunnels on the devices, due to the weak network model of linux any traffic destined for 10.1.1.1 on any interface would be forwarded correctly.

Source: [https://www.samba.org/~tpot/articles/multiple-interfaces.html](https://www.samba.org/%7Etpot/articles/multiple-interfaces.html)

Comment: I *need* Samba to listen on the tun* interfaces (as written in the question), but I need to remove them from my default name resolution. Just like Windows Servers do with unchecked "register interface in DNS".